# How do I Find and Replace in a specific GSheet column, using Script/Macros?

Tags: google-apps-script, replace

I'm building a tool in GSheets and I'm hitting a roadblock when it comes to automating the Find and Replace function using Scripts.

I'm able to run a basic F&R script that applies to the entire sheet (Found via another post on stack overflow), however, I need to apply this to specific columns, not the whole sheet.

e.g. - The current script in the below sheet finds any blank cell across the dataset and replaces it with 'BLANK'. I would like this to happen ONLY in column A of the sheet.

```
    function FandR(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName("Data Sheet");
  var f = "";
  var r = "BLANK";
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(data.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length;i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length;j++){
      if(data[j][i]==f)
      ss.getRange(j+1,i+1).setValue(r);
    }
  }  
}
```

Sample sheet here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/190J7AzKk4GsGSwPzvSNJau1cJKhlMQUJ87Uaavw7v8I/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below. The function will replace all FIND_TEXT in column A with REPLACE_TEXT .
If you want a more general solution that would replace all cells in the currently selected range, use `const frRange= sh.getActiveRange()`

```
function FandR(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Data Sheet");
  const FIND_TEXT = "";
  const REPLACE_TEXT = "BLANK";
  const frRange= sh.getRange("A:A")
  // can replace above line with: const frRange= sh.getActiveRange()
  const data = frRange.getValues()
  const newData = data.map(row=>row.map(cell=>cell==FIND_TEXT?REPLACE_TEXT:cell))
  frRange.setValues(newData)
}
```